# CoffeeScript Class Variable

Tags: javascript, class, variables, coffeescript

```
class Example
  constructor: ->
    $.each [1, 2, 3], (key, value) ->
      @test = value
    return @test
  render: ->
    alert @test

example = new Example()
example.render()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I'm using CoffeeScript (+ jQuery) and this is an class example where I would get the value 3 in @test variable. But this does not happen, can you help me?

Comment: A constructor can't return anything. An instance of the class is always returned when you instantiate a class. Doesn't have anything to do with your question but I thought I should let you know.

Comment: Correction for others reading along … constructors *absolutely can* return values; they simply must return an *object* (that is, no primitive values, such as numbers or strings.) (See: http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2, steps 9. and 10.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping problem:
`$.each` accepts a function, which has it's on scope, thus, your `this` variable is not the one you expected.

The working code:

```
class Example
  constructor: ->
    $.each [1, 2, 3], (key, value) =>
      @test = value
    return @test
  render: ->
    alert @test

example = new Example()
example.render()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

What changed? Check the arrow on the `$.each` call, it's now a fat arrow. Fat arrows does the trick of setting a _this variable and using it when you use `@...` making your scope the one you expected to be.

Check http://coffeescript.org on the section "Function Binding" for more details!